# Prove that $ta+(1-t)b \in I$ for all $t\in[0,1]$ without using the fact that an interval is convex?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $I=[\min\{a,b\},\max\{a,b\}]$.

Is it possible to give a simple proof that $ta+(1-t)b \in I$ for all $t\in[0,1]$ **without** using the fact that an interval is convex?

Comment: Why we need convexity at all? 

Comment: To avoid answers like "This is trivial since an interval is convex". I would like to actually write out a small proof.

Comment: One simplifying assumption in here is that $a<b$ without loss of generality. In that case it amounts to showing that $a<ta+(1-t)b<b$ for $0<t<1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For $t \in (0,1)$ and $a<b$,
$$a  = (1 + t-t) a = ta + (1 - t)a < ta + (1 - t)b < tb + (1 - t)b  = b$$
and we conclude.